# ASP Core HttpClientFactory Pattern Use Client Cert

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

Any one know how to use client cert when using the `HttpClientFactory`?  In all the examples I've found you need to provide an `HttpMessageHandler` in the `HttpClient` constructor, which isn't available when using the `HttpClientFactory`

```
        services.AddHttpClient("NamedClient", client =>
        {
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            X509Certificate2 certificate = GetMyX509Certificate();
            handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
            client. // ?? How do I set the handler?
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get it working with help from @agua from mars

```
        services.AddHttpClient("myservice", client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:8717");
        }).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(h =>
        {
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.ClientCertificates.Add(GetCert());
            return handler;
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You add a `HttpMessageHandler` in the http message handler pipeline using :

```
services.AddHttpMessageHandler<HttpClientHandler>()
```

And you register your handler using :

```
services.AddTransient(provider =>
{
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    X509Certificate2 certificate = GetMyX509Certificate();
    handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
    return handler;
});
```